# Weird result from Inversion of matrix using Package "Matrix" with negative sign in R

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-inverse

It is normal when using standard matrix function and get the inversion of negative matrix by solve()

```
B <- matrix(c(2,1,1,2),nrow=2,ncol=2)
solve(-B)
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.6666667  0.3333333
[2,]  0.3333333 -0.6666667
```

However it produce the opposite matrix when defining the matrix using "Matrix" Package

```
C <- Matrix(c(2,1,1,2),nrow=2,ncol=2)
solve(-C)
2 x 2 Matrix of class "dsyMatrix"
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.6666667 -0.3333333
[2,] -0.3333333  0.6666667
```

now solve(-C) is the same as solve(C), Why?

Comment: Given the answer from akrun, check what packages you are actually using. To be sure you are using the packages you think you are using, use `package::function_you_use()`, for example `reshape2::melt()`

Comment: could you please run this code in a **clean** R session and post the results of `sessionInfo()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all guys for helpful tips. I updated R from 4.0.3 to 4.1.0 and such issue has disappeared. It seems happens with the 4.0.3 version that `Matrix::solve(a+bM)` results inv(M) where M is defined by Matrix(data,now,ncol), in contrast to the standard small letters `base::matrix(data,nrow,ncol)`.

Answer (score 0):

In `R 4.1.0`, it gives the same output

```
> solve(-C)
2 x 2 Matrix of class "dsyMatrix"
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.6666667  0.3333333
[2,]  0.3333333 -0.6666667
> solve(-B)
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.6666667  0.3333333
[2,]  0.3333333 -0.6666667
```

---

There are multiple `methods` for `solve`

```
showMethods(solve)
```